# How to make view wrap label content on xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this kind of structure.

```
Content View
 -View
   --Label
   --Label
```

I want first Label to have one line and the second multiple lines. Also want to add some constraint to View also. But I got this result. (the view is cutting the text). I want to know how can make the view wrap the labels size. I am working with Xcode. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have fixed row height? Use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead

Comment: what constraint you set inside content view?

Comment: As suggested use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and For that, you need to have the constraints for cell and the `label_1` has `numberOfLines` as 1 and `label_2 numberOfLines` as 0. Here is the [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder, go to the Size inspection tab (where you see the constraints), and make sure to set the `Content Hugging Priority`'s `Vertical` value to a higher value, `1000` should work.
And same thing for `Content Compression Resistance Priority`.

[image]

Comment: @Merian Can you show us the constraints you setup for the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Set Top, Left, Right and Bottom constraints for view.

For label with single line content set Top, Left, Bottom and Right constraints

For label with multiple line set Left, Right and bottom constraints; Set Line Break property to Word Wrap and Line property to 0

Now, in viewDidLoad() set following two properties

self.tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 100

self.tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: I was thinkig for solving this without adding height dynamically. Flike form the xcode. That waybis working.